# Change subsequent values of columns of a row to 0 after first occurence of a 0

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following `data.table`:-

```
a <- data.table(name = letters[1:5], Y1 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0), Y2 = c(1,1,1,1,0),
                Y3 = c(1,1,1,0,1), Y4 = c(1,1,1,1,1), Y5 = c(0,0,0,0,1))

#   name Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5
#1:    a  1  1  1  1  0
#2:    b  1  1  1  1  0
#3:    c  0  1  1  1  0
#4:    d  1  1  0  1  0
#5:    e  0  0  1  1  1
```

I want to manipulate this `data.table` such that if a 0 is detected in a row for columns `Y1` to `Y5`, all the subsequent column values should be changed to 0. For example, for the `4`th row in the `data.table`, the first 0 is in `Y3`. Hence, `Y4` and `Y5` should be changed to 0. In `5`th row, the first 0 is present at `Y1` column, hence, `Y2` till `Y5` columns for that row should be changed to 0.

The resulting `data.table` should be as following:-

```
b <- a <- data.table(name = letters[1:5], Y1 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0), Y2 = c(1,1,0,1,0),
                 Y3 = c(1,1,0,0,0), Y4 = c(1,1,0,0,0), Y5 = c(0,0,0,0,0))

#   name Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5
#1:    a  1  1  1  1  0
#2:    b  1  1  1  1  0
#3:    c  0  0  0  0  0
#4:    d  1  1  0  0  0
#5:    e  0  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an option:

```
cols <- paste0("Y", 1L:5L)
a[, (cols) := lapply(Reduce(`&`, .SD, accumulate=TRUE), as.integer), .SDcols=cols]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can apply `cummin` rowwise -

```
cbind(a[, 1], t(apply(a[, -1], 1, cummin)))

#   name Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5
#1:    a  1  1  1  1  0
#2:    b  1  1  1  1  0
#3:    c  0  0  0  0  0
#4:    d  1  1  0  0  0
#5:    e  0  0  0  0  0
```